React Native Expo : NodePath has been removed. / React Native Testing Library : Trying to detect host component names triggered the following error :

    There seems to be an issue with your configuration that prevents React Native Testing Library from working correctly.
    Please check if you are using compatible versions of React Native and React Native Testing Library.

      28 | describe('Patients Category', () => {
      29 |     it('Correctly displays on the screen the patients and their items',async() => {
    > 30 |         const {getByText} = render(<PatientCategory />)
         |                                   ^
      31 |         await waitFor(() => {
      32 |             const patientName = getByText('Véronique')
      33 |             const patientStock = getByText('Blouse')

      at detectHostComponentNames (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/helpers/host-component-names.tsx:54:11)
      at detectHostComponentNames (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/helpers/host-component-names.tsx:27:30)
      at renderInternal (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/render.tsx:46:40)  
      at renderInternal (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/render.tsx:29:10)  
      at _callee$ (navigation/screens/Patients/PatientsCategory.test.js:30:35)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:45:16)        
      at Generator.<anonymous> (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:133:17)
      at Generator.next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:74:21)  
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24) 
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
      at node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:7
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:12)

Above is the error i get when i run npm run test
Below when i try to start my app with npx expo start
Android Bundling failed 12301ms (C:\Users\dmene\Documents\Code\GestionInventaire\node_modules\expo\Aerror: node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\RefreshControl\AndroidSwipeRefreshLayoutNativeComponent.js: C:\Users\dmene\Documents\Code\GestionInventaire\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\RefreshControl\AndroidSwipeRefreshLayoutNativeComponent.js: NodePath has been removed so is read-only.

This is my package.json
{
  "name": "gestioninventaire",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|firebase/.*)"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/audiowide": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native/babel-plugin-codegen": "^0.75.0-main",
    "@react-native/codegen": "^0.75.0-main",
    "@react-native/js-polyfills": "^0.74.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.74",
    "expo": "^50.0.14",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-expo": "~50.0.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

My babel config
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react',['module:@react-native/babel-preset', { "useTransformReactJSXExperimental": true }]],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
};

.babelrc
{
    "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }]
    ]
  }

The test file (i start by mocking a firebase data fetching using getDocs, then i render the component, await for the data to be fetched and check if everything renders as it should)
import { render, waitFor, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import React from "react";
import PatientCategory from "./PatientsCategory";

jest.mock('./PatientsCategory', () => ({
    db: {
      collection: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      getDocs: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        docs: [
          { id: '2', data: () => ({ Name: 'Véronique', CurrentStock: {name:"Gants non stériles",quantity:5}, ToOrder: [{}] }) },
          { id: '4', data: () => ({ Name: 'Jocelyne', CurrentStock: [{}], ToOrder: {} }) },
          { id: '5', data: () => ({ Name: 'Huguette J.', CurrentStock: [{name:'Gants stériles',quantity:4},{name:'Blouse',quantity:3}], ToOrder: [{}] }) },
          { id: '4', data: () => ({ Name: 'Jocelyne', CurrentStock: [{}], ToOrder: {} }) },
          { id: '6', data: () => ({ Name: 'Robert T.', CurrentStock: [{}], ToOrder: [{name:'Seringue', quantity:0}] }) },
        ]
      }),
      doc: jest.fn(),
      setDoc: jest.fn(),
      updateDoc: jest.fn(),
      arrayUnion: jest.fn(),
      deleteDoc: jest.fn()
    },
    auth: {
    }
  }));

describe('Patients Category', () => {
    it('Correctly displays on the screen the patients and their items',async() => {
        const {getByText} = render(<PatientCategory />)
        await waitFor(() => {
            const patientName = getByText('Véronique')
            const patientStock = getByText('Blouse')
            const patientToOrder = getByText('Seringue')

            expect(patientName).toBeInTheDocument()
            expect(patientStock).toBeInTheDocument()
            expect(patientToOrder).toBeInTheDocument()
        })
    })
})

I spent a few hours browsing the web to find a solution, trying everything i found, updating the dependencies version, installing new ones, modifying the babel config, even using chatGPT that can be quite useful sometimes but still, i can't figure out what's wrong
